# pip install --find-links html file format

Tags: python, jenkins, pip

I need to include a few python packages into my product, but the jenkins server that does the build does not have access to the Internet. I've downloaded one of the packages using pip download, which downloaded the package and all its dependencies. However, I need to make sure pip knows where to find those dependencies. I'm trying to use the options --no-index and --find-links with a path to an html file with links to those packages. The full command looks like this:

```
pip install http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/impyla-0.14.0.tar.gz --no-index --trusted-host SERVER --find-links http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/packages.html
```

...and the packages.html file looks like this:

```html
<a href="http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/bitarray-0.8.1.tar.gz">bitarray-0.8.1.tar.gz</a>
<a href="http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/ply-3.10.tar.gz">ply-3.10.tar.gz</a>
<a href="http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl">six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl</a>
<a href="http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/thriftpy-0.3.9.tar.gz">thriftpy-0.3.9.tar.gz</a>
```

However, when jenkins tries to run these commands, I get:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   thriftpy>=0.3.5 (from impyla==0.14.0) (from versions: )
>
> No matching distribution found for thriftpy>=0.3.5 (from
>   impyla==0.14.0)

I'm wondering if my packages.html isn't in a correct format, but I can't find any examples of using an html file for dependency resolution. Has anyone used --find-links successfully?

Comment: Can you paste the output of your pip command with `-vvv` ?

Comment: I added -v and it gave me the answer!
Skipping page http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/packages.html because of Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

The repo where I'm serving the html file does not set the Content-Type properly. Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [emulbreh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/641234/emulbreh) I added -v to the pip install command and it reported:

> Skipping page http://SERVER/python-packages/impyla/0.14.0/packages.html
>   because of Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8

Once I made sure the html file is served with a proper Content Type, I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I never saw a requirements file in html format but maybe is possible, the examples in official doc are .txt files but I think your trouble is another thing for example you must check the following the architectural of the operative system where you did the download of the package because this package are bind to that architectural I mean 64bit or 32bit, the other thing is to check you have same python interpreter or another one compatible with the one where you did the packages download, all that things are important, even if it is not important for you to keep the version of `thriftpy` do not specify a version for this package and delete it from the requirement file and let the pip find the mayor version who works for you that is what happen if you do not specify a version for a package.

Comment: According to pip documentation for find-links:

If a url or path to an html file, then parse for links to archives. If a local path or file:// url that's a directory, then look for archives in the directory listing.

I'm not worried about the architecture - the machine I used to pip download the packages is the same type of machine the product is going to be deployed on. Thanks!